# How can I stop caching of Oracle Select statement in PHP?

Tags: php, oracle, caching

I have a basic SQL select statement in PHP that I pass off to an oracle server.

```
$queryString = "
            SELECT /*+ NOCACHE */
                company,
                addr1,
                addr2,
                addr3,
                city,
                state,
                country,
                zip,                    
                custno CUSTOMERNUMBER,
                prime_contact PRIMECONTACT,
                prime_contact_email PRIMEEMAIL,
                phone_number PRIMEPHONE,
                ext PRIMEEXTN,
                fax_number PRIMEFAX,
                ID
            FROM               
                IQMS.ARCUSTO 
            WHERE 
                ID=" . $ID;


        $stid = oci_parse($OracleConnection, $queryString);
        oci_execute($stid);

        $row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC);

        oci_free_statement($stid);
        oci_close($OracleConnection);
```

When I execute the query n- it will pull up the latest changes if I've left it the app alone for a while.  If I run the app often, it seems to cache the query, even with no cache hint in the query.

I can't really flush the cache on the server as we are in a prod environment and really don't want to slow down the other applications using the data.

How can I get my query to return the changed results when run as often as every 5 min?

Comment: One side comment: using `"... ID=" . $ID` is a security hole and impacts scalability.  You MUST use a bind variable (check all the doc, examples [etc](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html)).  Do you actually have result caching enabled - p 176 on the doc I just linked to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I don't think database can provide wrong results because of caching. The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGDBA/tune_result_cache.htm#TGDBA618) says the following

"When users execute queries and functions repeatedly, the database retrieves rows from the cache, decreasing response time. Cached results become invalid when data in dependent database objects is modified."

So I'd suggest you either to check if the data was really updated or to look for cached results on another application layer.

Again, sorry for an not helping answer